# django.db.migrations.exceptions.InconsistentMigrationHistory: Migration socialaccount.0001_initial is applied before its dependency sites.0001_initial

Tags: django, database, postgresql, makemigrations

Django==4.2.4
In production, postgresql. In local, sqlite(django's default)

```py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'snsapp.apps.SnsappConfig',My app
    
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount',
    'bleach',
    'widget_tweaks',
    'django_ckeditor_5',

    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites', Added
    'django.contrib.sitemaps',Added
]
```

I added site and sitemap to create a sitemap.

Then, executed this command in local

```
python3 manage.py migrate

    raise InconsistentMigrationHistory(
django.db.migrations.exceptions.InconsistentMigrationHistory: Migration socialaccount.0001_initial is applied before its dependency sites.0001_initial on database 'default'.
```

How can I resolve this? I want to avoid deleting data and experiencing downtime because I've already released this product.

PS.
Since allauth.socialaccount was not used by me, I solved the problem by deleting it from installed_apps and migrate.
If there is data in socialaccount, I think makemigrations, then migrate, then delete the data, then add sites and migrate.

The cause is that I didn't write 'django.contrib.sites' together. During the learning process, I didn't write it because I didn't think it had anything to do with allauth at a glance. Also, I think if you use them together, you need to put them above socialaccount or you will get an error (because the social account migration is applied before sites).

I'm sure there are others who have similar questions, so I'll leave the question as is.

Sites that might be helpful

https://medium.com/@damngoodtech/how-to-solve-django-db-migrations-exceptions-inconsistentmigrationhistory-when-running-migrate-6e8f4e60fbbe

Now it looks like you have to be a paying member to see it. I was able to see it before. It is the exact same error and the same cause. I think the content was something about making a backup and deleting the file. In that case, wouldn't it be unusable during that time? I think so, but depending on the situation, this may solve the problem.

I didn't write how to reproduce it.

```
'allauth',
'allauth.account',.
'allauth.socialaccount',
```

and migrate, then add 'django.contrib.sites' and migrate, you will get the same error.